# JavaFX splitting Clipboard getString() strange behavior

Tags: java, string, javafx, clipboard, splitter

I made a program using JavaFX where I have to paste into an excel like table.

I followed some tutorials online but noticed strange behavior in the way the paste code functions. After a while, I isolated the problem to the following code.

```
public void handlePaste() {
    Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();

    if (clipboard.hasString()) {
        //start from the point that has focus
        // abort if there's not cell selected to start with
        if (getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().size() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // get the cell position to start with
        TablePosition pasteCellPosition = getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();

        String pasteString = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getString();

        int rowClipboard = -1;

        Iterable<String> rowStrings = Splitter.on("\n").omitEmptyStrings().split(pasteString);
        System.out.println("Print Rows");
        for (String rowString : rowStrings) {
            System.out.println(rowString);
            System.out.println(rowString + "  printing again");
        }

        for (String rowString : rowStrings) {
            rowClipboard++;
            Iterable<String> columnStrings = Splitter.on("\t").split(rowString);

            int colClipboard = -1;
            System.out.println("Printing Columns");
            for (String columnString : columnStrings) {
                System.out.println(columnString);
                System.out.println(columnString + "  printing again");
            }
         }
    }
}
```

I use the output statement to demonstrate the problem.
Basically, I'm splitting the contents of the string based off and '\n' and '\t' characters.
The problem is whenever I try to do anything with the split strings, the string just...DISAPPEARS...
The output statements I put in demonstrate this.

Suppose the string on the clipboard is

```
l   a
l   b
l   c
```

Then the expected output should be

```
Print rows
l   a
l   a printing again
l   b
l   b printing again
r   c
r   c printing again
Printing Columns
l
l again
a
a again
l
l again
b
b again
r
r again
c
c again
```

But the output ends up being

```
Print rows
l   a
 printing again
l   b
 printing again
r   c
 printing again
Printing Columns
l
 again
a
 again
l
 again
b
 again
r
 again
c
 again
```

Notice how when I try to append " printing again" to the split string, I'm simply getting blank strings.

I tried fixing the issue by using substring, and by using the standard java string splitting methods and I got the same behavior.

Finally, to fix it, I just used the java.awt Clipboard instead of the JavaFX clipboard and suddenly...it worked!

```
        java.awt.Toolkit toolkit = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard awtClipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
        try {
            pasteString = (String) awtClipboard.getData(java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
        } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex) {

        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
```

Using the above line of code to get the pasteString instead of the JavaFX clipboard fixed the problem, and now I get the expected behavior and output.

For now, I will stick with the above fix, but it seems strange that the JavaFX clipboard is producing this behavior when the awt clipboard does not. Can anybody explain why this is happening? Is this a bug with the JavaFX clipboard?

Comment: Using `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead of `"\n"` fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you. This appears to be working.

Answer (score 0):

LuxxMiner's comment above appears to offer a solution.

Using `System.lineSeparator()` also seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I found the above solutions didn't quite work out for me. The problem is that while the system seperator does get me the seperator for my systems, when I copy and paste from another program, it isn't guaranteed that the program I'm copying from is using the systems' seperator. For instance, when I copied from an excel spreadsheet, I kept getting the same strange behavior I got before, and I believe it was because excel didn't use the systems seperator.

So this is the solution I eventually came upon...
Basically it looks for ANY of the basic line seperators and splits on them.

```
import com.google.common.base.CharMatcher;
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
Iterable<String> rowStrings = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf("\n\r")).omitEmptyStrings().split(pasteString);
```